# I want to take data from sql lite database and display it on a graph view using a list view that is populated by group names

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-graphview

i have been trying for a while to populate a graph view with data from my sql lite database. i believe i have everything needed within the code. but i do not know how to work out the onItemClick method. i have a list view of groups, i want to take the data from a selected group and display it on the graph. this is all happening on the same screen

```
public class Main_graph_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

PieChart pieChart;

Long k;
int j;
FloatingActionButton fb;
String j1;
TextView noDet;
SQLiteDatabase dbgroup=null;
FloatingActionButton f;
ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> list_item = new ArrayList<>();
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>();
Vector<Integer> vec = new Vector<>();
int count=0;
add_adapter adapter;
List<additem> niitemlist;
ArrayAdapter adapter1;
ListView listView;
ListView listView1;
private ArrayList<PieEntry> yValues;
String p;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_graph_activity);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    fillActivity();
    setTitle("Graphs");

    listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_below_2);

    pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);
    Legend legend = pieChart.getLegend();
    legend.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    legend.setTextSize(15f);

    pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
    pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
    pieChart.setExtraOffsets(5,10,5,5);

    pieChart.setDragDecelerationFrictionCoef(0.15f);

    pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
    pieChart.setHoleColor(Color.WHITE);
    pieChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(61f);

    //ArrayList<PieEntry> yValues = new ArrayList<>();

    yValues = new ArrayList<>();

    //plotter();

   // Description description = new Description();
    //description.setText(" This graph shows all bills");
    //description.setTextSize(15);
    //pieChart.setDescription(description);

    pieChart.animateY(1000, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutCubic);

    PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(yValues, ": Countries");
    dataSet.setSliceSpace(3f);
    dataSet.setSelectionShift(5f);
    dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);

    PieData data = new PieData((dataSet));
    data.setValueTextSize(20f);
    data.setValueTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

    pieChart.setData(data);

    //this is code to click into different groups
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    TextView temp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    String str = temp.getText().toString();
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Main_graph_activity.class);
                    in.putExtra("id", str);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            }
    );


}

//method to populate graph
public void plotter() {
    dbgroup=this.openOrCreateDatabase("grouptwo.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
   // Intent in=Main_graph_activity.this.getIntent();
   // Intent in = getIntent();
   // Bundle bundle = in.getExtras();
   // p = bundle.getString("id");


    //Bundle p = getIntent().getExtras();
    // if (p != null)
    //{
     //bundle.getString("id");
    // }






    dbgroup.execSQL("create table if not exists " + p + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,friend_name TEXT,note TEXT,amount TEXT)");
    Cursor c = dbgroup.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + p + ";", null);
    if (c != null) {
        int i = 0;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                //create list view from table group_name
                String d2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("friend_name"));
                String d1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("note"));
                String d4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("amount"));
                vec.add(1);
                yValues.add(new PieEntry(Integer.parseInt(d4), d2));
                //niitemlist.add(new item(d1,d4,d2));

                pieChart = (PieChart) findViewById(R.id.piechart);




                //add to chart...

            } while (c.moveToNext());

            pieChart.getData();


        }
    }
}


//function to fill up the activitys list view to show groups to click
void fillActivity() {
    dbgroup = openOrCreateDatabase("grouptwo.db", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    niitemlist = new ArrayList<>();
    listView =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_below_2);
    dbgroup.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Group_details (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,group_name TEXT NOT NULL, date_go DATE NOT NULL, " + "friend_no INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)");
    Cursor c = dbgroup.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Group_details ORDER BY date_go DESC;", null);
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst())

            do {

                String d4 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("group_name"));
                final Long d1 = c.getLong((c.getColumnIndex("date_go")));
                String d2 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date_go"));
                String temp = d4;
                niitemlist.add(new additem(d4, d2));
                vec.add(1);
                j++;
            } while (c.moveToNext());

    }
    adapter = new add_adapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.add_text, niitemlist);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);



}



public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```